# php : is this if condition correct?

Tags: php

I have the following if condition statement

```
if ( (strlen($data[70])>0) || ( (remove19((trim($data[29])) == '7135556666')) && isLongDistance($data[8]))  )
```

where $data is a recordset from a database.

My goal is to include all rows where $data[70] isn't blank, and also include rows where $data[29] = 713555666 && $data[8] isLongDistance = TRUE

My question is, if isLongDistance($data[8]) returns false, will it still return the row since $data[70] is not blank?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you're doing an OR.  Your statement will reduce to "TRUE OR (TRUE AND FALSE)", which will be TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you have an OR operator.

Answer (score 0):

If the first thing returns TRUE then the if will succeed. If first thing will return FALSE, then it will execute the part after OR and if the number is correct and the function returns TRUE, then it will succeed.

Anyway I would overwrite it like this

```
if ( !empty($data[70]) or ( (int)$data[29] == 7135556666 and isLongDistance($data[8]) )
```

Comment: empty() will evaluate to true if $data[70] = '0'. Perhaps his application must consider that to be a valid value, hence strlen(). The remove19 may be doing something important and perhaps shouldn't be removed. Also, casting $data[29] to int will result in true when it contains 7135556666.43. Perhaps he needs such a value to evaluate to false. We don't know. Also, phill should be made aware that || and && have different operator precedence than "or" and "and" and can also be much more readable in long conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. But to understand realy what it does write code that humans can understand, dont write code just for the computers.

consider this simplefied version.

```
$dataLenght   =  strlen($data[70]);
$remove19     =  remove19((trim($data[29]);
$longDistance = isLongDistance($data[8]);


if ( $dataLenght > 0 ) // your first OR if false it would goto elseif statement
{
  //condition
}

elseif( $remove19 == '7135556666'  && $longDistance) // your second statement 
{
  //conditon

}
```